# HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized for sendgrid integration with python

Tags: python-2.7, sendgrid

```
def sendEmail(to,apNumber,paperType,zipedFile):

    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get("API-KEY"))

    to_email = mail.Email( "to@email.com")
    from_email = mail.Email( "from@email.com" )
    subject = 'This is a test email'
    content = mail.Content('text/plain', 'Example message.')
    message = mail.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body = message.get())
    return response
```

Comment: Are you sure the `API-KEY` environment variable is set? What OS are you using (`API-KEY` is a valid env variable name on Windows, but *nix doesn't allow `-` in the name).

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.0. may i know how to set environment variable for api

Comment: You'd usually export it in the shell before running your program, e.g. `export API_KEY="..."` - read more [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setup Environment Variables.

To Set up environment Variable follow the below 3 steps

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

Comment: Yeah, after setting the environment variable my problem got solved

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
    import os
    from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
    from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
    message = Mail(
            from_email='...@gmail.com',
            to_emails='....@gmail.com',
            subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',    
            html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
    try:
    **sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))**

        response = sg.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I got the same error `"UnauthorizedError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"`

I refactored the code from
`sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))`

to

`sg=SendGridAPIClient('......IeltIytmFYeQ0aSOt2UBYvv2E6Xh...')`

Then it started working.

I change my API key settings to Full access in SendGrid portal.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" error in PHP. See the screenshot.

[image]

I solved it by removing `getenv()` from the API key.

Replace:

```
$apiKey = getenv("SendGrid_API_Key");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
```

with:

```
$apiKey = ("SendGrid_API_Key");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that though

```
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
```

worked fine when the script was called from the terminal, but it did not when it was called from my a javascript file in the browser. It's because the os.environ.get was actually different in that case.
Directly having the API_KEY was the solution:

```
sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key='SG.tbd')
```

Comment: But isn't this unsafe? Shouldn't the api key be stored as an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new key and that solved my issue. Exact issue for this is still unknown.
As it was functional before.

Answer (score 0):

The error for me was because I used the wrong key , actually, one needs to use the key that is created the first time when one create the Api key  , which one cannot edit again. So one have to click "Create Api key" button and use this key